# Is it possible to run pulse callibrated gates on a simulated ibm backend

Tags: qiskit, simulation

Currently I am trying to test a quantum algorithm that consists of calibrated quantum gates on a circuit. It needs to stay this way because I would like to run the algorithm on a real backend in the future. Is there a way to make a pulse simulator that can run pulse calibrated quantum gates? Currently I can't use the PulseSimulator because no IBMQ backends support open pulse anymore. The Aer.from_backend() also doesn't allow callibrated gates. Is the only way I can run a pulse circuit on a simulator using scheduled circuits?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know exactly what you are trying to accomplish without a code example, but I think you can do this with the [FakeOpenPulse2Q](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.39/stubs/qiskit.providers.fake_provider.FakeOpenPulse2Q.html#qiskit.providers.fake_provider.FakeOpenPulse2Q) fake provider:

```
...    

backend = FakeOpenPulse2Q()
pulse_sim = qiskit_aer.PulseSimulator.from_backend(backend)

...

pulse_qobj = assemble(schedules, backend=backend_sim)
results = backend_sim.run(pulse_qobj)
```